# How to override Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method?

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I want to override this core model of magento and follow is my code , i have no idea why its not working

```
<global>
    <models>
        <shipping_rate>
            <rewrite>
                <result_method>Mcc_Customshippingprice_Model_Rate_Result_Method</result_method>
            </rewrite>
        </shipping_rate>
    </models>
</global>
```

and this is model class

```
class Mcc_Customshippingprice_Model_Rate_Result_Method extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method {
    public function setPrice($price) {
        $this->setData('price', 1999);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have a question, explain what the problem is and what you have tried, and do some research before you come to us for help, =because often times a simple search can yield the answer you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for reply Evan i want to override setPrice in Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method but its not working

Comment: Do you at any point call it in your main script? It is easiest to call the variable and subsequently override it in the main script.

Comment: Do you have all the required file for it to work ? The right xml in `app/etc/modules/` ? Is the part of your `config.xml` displayed here in the right nodes ? Is the file itself in the right place ? What error are you getting ?
More info would help to get you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is `Mage_Shipping` with the code `shipping` and the class you want to rewrite has the alias `shipping/rate_result_method`, not `shipping_rate/result_method`, so the right way is:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <shipping>
            <rewrite>
                <rate_result_method>Mcc_Customshippingprice_Model_Rate_Result_Method</rate_result_method>
            </rewrite>
        </shipping>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay fschmengler i also try that but it still not working i want to override setPrice method in this class